# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'Decimal128'

Tags: python, django, database, mongodb, django-models

I'm trying to add the numbers from the MongoDB database.

```
meal_data = Data.objects.filter(year= se_year, month= se_month, category = 'Meal')
    meal_amt = 0
    for i in meal_data:
        id = i.id
        m_amount_data = Data.objects.get(id = id)
        meal_amt += m_amount_data.amount
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'Decimal128'

The error is showing in this line.

```
meal_amt += m_amount_data.amount
```

I need to add those numbers and store them in a variable `meal_amt`.

Comment: The error is explaining to you what's wrong: Python doesn't know how to add an `int` and a `Decimal128`, which means you have to change one of the types to the other. The question is, what type should your answer have?

Answer (score 1):

change the type of `meal_amt` variable into Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal

meal_data = Data.objects.filter(year= se_year, month= se_month, category = 'Meal')
meal_amt = Decimal(0)

for i in meal_data:
    meal_amt += i.amount
```

Also, no need to fetch the Data object in for loop.

Comment: No bro not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `aggregate` function to get the total sum like so:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

meal_amt = Data.objects.filter(
    year=se_year, 
    month=se_month, 
    category='Meal'
).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
```

This should have better performance comparing with what you're already doing since we are not looping through the records but getting the sum straight from the database instead.

Comment: Thanks bro it worked. My bad :) still noob.

Comment: Happy to help. Can you accept this answer as the solution?